# Which German language newspapers offer APIs?

Tags: software

I would like to access good quality German news articles regularly, particularly their textual data in an efficient and easy manner to possibly do some minor programmatic manipulation of it, for example to build some elementary reading interfaces for it, because I want to build tools with which I will practice reading German.

Which German newspapers offer an API by which you can retrieve new article content? Free or paid.

Thanks very much

Comment: Not sure they do - why would they? HTML and their website is after all the API they like to present their content. But have a look at https://www.dkriesel.com/spiegelmining - however I'm not sure this question is on-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not really about any aspect of the German language (the topic of this board).

Comment: https://upload-magazin.de/6778-offene-medien-ein-uberblick-uber-apis-bei-verlagen-und-co/#APIs_bei_deutschen_Verlagen and further search for "api zeitung" or similar might give further results. There seem to be legal shenengians in offering it as many links seem a bit dated. The Deutsche Digitale Bibliothek (DDB) offers API to "historic" articles, thus does focus more on a comprehensive archive than offering the latest. https://deepnote.com/@karl-kragelin-b83c/Zeitungsportal-API-2SJN2o4mSzWm10DpUHsRUQ

Comment: This is an IT-question, not a question about aspects of German language. It is off-topic here.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast I can respect that, however, I noticed there was another accepted question on this site about APIs, and the point of the question is software to assist German language learning, which is basically a resource request, which I have observed is accepted. For example, my question about German podcasts was accepted, and I see this question as being in the same line. But I can accept it being closed.

Comment: I would look for RSS feeds, some newspapers still have them.

Comment: This not so much an IT question, but rather a question for quite specific German ressources.

Comment: If your question doesn't work out here, you might want to consider [opendata.se].

Answer (score 1):

DPA (Deutsche Presseagentur, the main news provider in Germany) offers an [API](https://service.dpa-infocom.de/de/support/solutions/76000002200) (obviously, payable).

AFP (Agence France Press, the DPA's French counterpart), also offers (payable) [APIs](https://developers.afp.com/de) for News in German.

It's pretty unlikely you will find a free API for editorial contents anywhere. A viable alternative would be scraping pages from popular news outlets like Der Spiegel, which actually isn't that hard. There is even a "Spiegel" scraping API on [Github](https://github.com/ietz/spiegel-api)